# Select statement within a case statement

Tags: sql

Will appreciate some help with this question:

```
A (userid)      B(userid)

1                   2
2                   5
3                   7
4
5
6
7
```

Given a table A (userid) and a table B (userid), we have to write a query who's result set is two fields (1) all of A users and (2) whether those users exist in B

Will query # 1 (below) work? If not, please explain why it won't work.

```
Resultset: 

userid    is_in_a
1              0
2              1
3              0
4              0
5              1
6              0
7              0
```

## Solution 1: Query with select inside case

```
Select A.id, 
    case when exists ((select B.id from B where B.id=A.id) 
        then 1 else 0) as is_in_A
             from A
```

## Solution 2: Query with Left Outer Join

```
Select userid, case userid
           (when IS NULL then 0
           else 1) as is_in_A
from
  (Select userid
   from A left outer join B on a.userid = B.userid)
```

Thanks

Comment: _"Will query # 1 (below) work?"_ Well? Did you try it, on whatever mysterious implementation of SQL you're using that you didn't tag?

Comment: First information you should give is which dbms you are using.  Secondly, have you run those queries and see which one works before asking question?

Comment: Thank you. I am a noob, did try it, but wasn't sure whether it was a conceptual problem or an implementation mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```
Select A.id,
       (case when exists (select 1from B where B.id = A.id) then 1 else 0 end) as is_in_A
from A;
```

Your queries have unnecessary parentheses and are missing the `end` for the `case`.

Answer (score 0):

This query should work:

```
select A.userid, case when B.userid is null then 0 else 1 end as is_in_a
from A
left join B on B.userid = A.userid 
Order By A.userid
```